# Angular JS route, http and json strange works

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am a newbie in `Angular JS`. I am replacing a webapp from jquery and PHP to Angular JS + PHP (PHP is necessary to get data from DB and pass it on JSON).

The PHP module works, I have tested. My problem is on AngularJS.

This is index.html

```
<body ng-app="manager">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="managerController as menuManager">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Manager</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active" ng-repeat="voce in menuManager.voce"><a href="#/{{voce.url}}">{{voce.nome}}</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is manager.js

```
var app = angular.module('manager', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when("/a",{templateUrl:"a.html",controller:"aCtrl"})
            .when("/b",{templateUrl:"b.html",controller:"bCtrl"})
            .when("/c",{templateUrl:"c.html",controller:"cCtrl"})
            .when("/d",{templateUrl:"d.html",controller:"dCtrl"});     }]);

app.controller('managerController',function(){
    this.voce = menu;
});

menu = [
        {'nome':'A', 'url':'a'},
        {'nome':'B', 'url':'b'},
        {'nome':'C', 'url':'c'},
        {'nome':'D', 'url':'d'}
       ];
```

This is the aCtrl.js

```
app.controller("aCtrl", function($http,$scope){
    $http.post("../../qry_select.php",{"payload":"manager"})
        .success(function(data){
            alert("Work!");
            $scope.content = data;
            })
        .error(function(){
            alert ("Doesn't work");
            });
});
```

and this is the aView.html

```
<div ng-controller="aCtrl">
   <p>{{content}}</p>
</div>
```

My problems are:

1. Work alert is showed twice (?)
2. Content is blank
3. Firebug shows me just qry_select.php send data, not received data

Please help me

Comment: Your angular project and web services are works as single folder?

Comment: No, i've replaced path. I've follow this guide 
[link] https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure

Comment: You should add `.otherwise()` option when configure $routeProvider . May be because none routes are matched the content is blank.

`.when("/d",{templateUrl:"d.html",controller:"dCtrl"})
.otherwise({templateUrl:"aView.html",controller:"aCtrl"});`

Comment: @SlavaN. i've checked setting an attribute on view and it's work. Also the alert works too (but twice)...

Comment: Try: `$http.post("../../qry_select.php",{"payload":"manager"})
    .then(function(data) {
        alert("Work!!")
        $scope.content = data;
    }, function(response) {
        alert ("Doesn't work");
    });` and see if it will show alert 2 times.

Comment: @developer033 yes it works, but i have this errorError: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/ng/areq?p0=aCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

but this is ok

Comment: Do you have 2 different controllers in your file?

Comment: no just this in this file

Comment: If alert fires twice you have 2 instances of same controller somehow. Are controllers defined in route config and ng-controller? Only need one, usually route config

Comment: @charlietfl great! i didn't know. Ok, but now how can i see the received data from PHP?

Comment: log it to browser dev tools console or inspect actual request in browser dev tools network

Comment: do it, but i cannot see response data... it' s strange, call qry_select with jquery (webapp old version) it works...
@charlietfl one question: if i pull out the controller from ng-controller in the view, can i call the content attribute as before? {{content}} ?? regards :-)

Comment: sorry for the late... qry_select send me json data, so i need to get them from AngularJS with JSON.stringify(data). 
Now it works. Thank @all